# how to disable google chrome suggestion list when using twitter bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

using twitter bootstrap typeahead i get  google chrome suggestion list above typeahead list

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[ID$=TextBox]").typeahead({ source: ["aaa", "aab", "aac", "aad"] });
    });

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" data-provide="typeahead"></asp:TextBox>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `autocomplete="off"` on the input box?

Comment: you are right
please write it as answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Follow-up from the comment section above]

You can turn off that feature on the input box that the typehead is referenced from by setting the autocomplete function off like so:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Comment: Just a note for clarity that "autocomplete" is only HTML5, so if you're using some other DOCTYPE, it won't validate.

Answer (score 4):

As Andres Ilich mentioned, adding `autocomplete="off"`attribute should do the trick. It is mentioned in W3 draft:
http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete

I do not know much about ASP.NET and so I do not know whether that attribute is supported in  tag. When I browsed w3school (http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_textbox_autocompletetype.asp) I got this as familiar option `AutoCompleteType="None"`. But I am not sure of this.

I think in jQuery you can implement something like this:

`$("[ID$=TextBox]").attr("autocomplete", "off");`