# autocomplete="off" not working for Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, autocomplete

This question has been asked Several times in the past but unfortunately there's no way i could disable autofill for Google Chrome (v.36.0.1985.125 m)

I have already Tried

["AutoComplete=Off" not working on Google Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306052/autocomplete-off-not-working-on-google-chrome-browser)

[How do I stop Chrome from pre-populating input boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999578/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-pre-populating-input-boxes)

[how to disable google chrome suggestion list when using twitter bootstrap typeahead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565486/how-to-disable-google-chrome-suggestion-list-when-using-twitter-bootstrap-typeah)

Code tested so far

```
<form autocomplete="off">

<asp:textbox autocomplete="off">

AutoCompleteType="Disabled"
```

But I still get autofiled data on my login page. Passwords are populated even if Textbox Ids are changed.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: as of 31/12/2022, the solution "new-password" seems to be adaptable to any registered form data inside Chromium based browsers : for example if you add autocomplete="new-user-street-address-email-password-phone" to your form as attribute, the corresponding data will not be autocompleted.

Answer (score 8):

Since I have been having this very same issue and it seems all "alternatives" stopped working as the browsers have been getting recent updates, I came across a "dirty" solution that baffled me completely.

If we go on each field we want to disable the autocomplete feature and set its autocomplete attribute to an invalid value (only "off" and "on" are valid), the browser will stop trying to autofill those fields because of that.

Surprised? So was I!

Example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="stopdoingthat" />
```

And apparently it works. Stupid, I know, but it's a "dirty" one that actually works for now.

Comment: This worked for me to stop autofill on chrome where nothing else I found worked. Thanks!!

Comment: See comment 164 for an explanation about why this works (and why Google is, again, taking the annoying "We know better than you" position ... feels like the IE days, doesn't it?) [chromium bug 468153 comment 164](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164)

Answer (score 2):

**Recent Version of Google Chrome are forcing Autofill irrespective of the `Autocomplete=off` .** You are going to need little bit of hack here. Some of the previous hacks don't work anymore (34+ versions)

**I have tested following code on Google Chrome v36.**

It removes "name" and "id" attributes from elements and assigns them back after 1ms. This works perfectly in my case.

Put this code in document ready.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$('form[autocomplete="off"] input, input[autocomplete="off"]').each(function () {

                var input = this;
                var name = $(input).attr('name');
                var id = $(input).attr('id');

                $(input).removeAttr('name');
                $(input).removeAttr('id');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(input).attr('name', name);
                    $(input).attr('id', id);
                }, 1);
            });
         });;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.Net TextBox adding TextMode="Search" and AutoCompleteType="Disabled" worked for me

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddress" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Search" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

and i tested this in both Edge (Version 89.0.774.48) and Chrome (Version 88.0.4324.190 )

Answer (score 0):

This readonly-fix worked for me:

**fix browser autofill in: readonly and set writeble on focus** (at mouse click and tabbing through fields)

```
 <input type="password" readonly  
     onfocus="$(this).removeAttr('readonly');"/>
```

By the way, **some more information** on Chrome and Safari auto fill behaviour:

*Sometimes even autocomplete=off would not prevent to fill in credentials* into wrong fields, but not user or nickname field. I guess, the Chrome and Safari look for a password field to insert your saved credentials. Then it **autofills *username* into the nearest textlike-input field , that appears prior the password field** in DOM (just guessing due to observation). As the browser is the last instance and you can not directly control it, but the read-only trick above fixes it. :-)

Comment: Didn't work for me, Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd update this with a 2016 post. I used a combo of both [Sangram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443244/sangram)'s solution, as well as [dsuess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2354488/dsuess)'. This is working for me as of the time of this post.

Sangram's solution unfortunately no longer worked for me with a later Chrome version, but using dsuess' method of marking the fields as readonly, while not visually appealing (since they stay readonly until you actually focus on the element, which isn't the most intuitive way to do it - but whatever works, right?), did still work.

By combining the two, we no longer require the user to focus on the field. Here is my web page code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TeamName" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Which, for the curious, after being parsed by IIS, renders to the following raw HTML:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$uc_CreateTeam$TeamName" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="MainContent_uc_CreateTeam_TeamName" readonly="readonly">
```

The accompanying js:

```js
// Disable autocomplete for form fields. This is done by setting the 'autocomplete' attribute (which is deprecated)
// as an indicator that we want this field to not be autofilled. We also set these forms to load as readonly (which
// will cause browsers to ignore them), and now we mark them writable.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form[autocomplete="off"] input, input[autocomplete="off"]').each(function() {
    var input = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(input).removeAttr('readonly');
    }, 200); // 100 does not work - too fast.
  });
});
```

Hopefully this helps any stragglers still looking for the solution a few years later!

Answer (score 0):

Look, the only way to fix this is to petition the Chromium developers.  Get on their forums and tell them what a pain this is.  Every workaround is eventually destroyed by them.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914451

As of right now, having a unique ID on the control fixes it.

My recommendation is to use the user's session ID as part of the control ID on the page.  That currently works across the board.  But it won't forever.

Answer (score 0):

Make type of password field as 'text' and change it to 'password' on click.

HTML:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id='username'>
<input autocomplete="off" id='password' type="text" onclick="changeType('password')">
```

js:

```
changeType(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('type', 'password');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

work  for   me  :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox"  runat="server" Text='mootez'onfocus="this.autocomplete='off'" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion change the name of the control. For example, I had a control named txtFirsName and always it showed me autocomplete suggestions, I changed by txtFN and Ready!