# AutoComplete always is enabled even after setting to OFF

Tags: c#, autocomplete

For my web application, I have verified autocomplete on firefox and it works great. Whereas the same fails for chrome. I don't want AutoComplete for particular textbox or that form. But chrome still keeps filling it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeSearch" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

Tried to disable autocomplete option from form but still it doesn't work for chrome.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

Please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [autocomplete="off" not working for Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228951/autocomplete-off-not-working-for-google-chrome)

Comment: Even after removing either of them, the problem is still present with chrome. What I have observed is, chrome by default fills the password at the login page, and when I navigate to another page which has textbox of password type, it automatically fills them. 

Whereas mozilla firefox, at login page, only on double clicking the textbox fills the password. Just wanted to know if something can be done for this issue.!!

Answer (score 0):

We were able to disable using JQuery in Chrome like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off");

    });
```

Doesn't seem to work in IE 11 though.