# Disable browser's autofill when using typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead.js

As seen in the 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjNNB.jpg) - how can one disable autofill when using typeahead ?

Thank you.

PS:

browser used is Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Add `autocomplete="unique-field-name"` and make sure the field has a `name="unique-name"` attribute.

For me, using 63.0.3239.132 Chrome, with 0.11.1 Typeahead.js, this was the only way to reliably stop Google Chrome autofilling my typeahead. (Typeahead seems to copy over autocomplete="off" but that seems to be being ignored by Chrome currently.)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<input type="search" autocomplete="off">
```

Works on Chrome:
Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Yes! This works in old school asp.net: `TextBox.Attributes["type"] = "search"; TextBox.Attributes["autocomplete"] = "off";`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `autocomplete="off"` Attribute to your input field:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Best Wishes

Comment: Hi @winston. Thank you. Unfortunately I've already tried that pearl, and it didn't affect the effect.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! have you taken a look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228951/autocomplete-off-not-working-for-google-chrome) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/29582380#29582380) thread?

Comment: You saved my day, winston. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach no longer works as modern browsers ignore it

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, once you have initialised the typeahead binding on the control in your js, just add some additional code to set the autocomplete attribute to 'new-password'.

```
$('#typeahead-field').attr("autocomplete", "new-password");
```

This works as of Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (May 2020)